# Return line conditonally on next line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to return a list of  IP Addresses for computers that have a windows OS (for my security course). The output is in this format

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.xx.xxx
Host is up (0.066s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
MAC Address:

Host script results:
| smb-os-discovery: 
|   OS: Windows Server (R) 2008 Standard 6001 Service Pack 1 (Windows Server (R) 2008 Standard 6.0)
|   OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2008::sp1
|   Computer name: 
|   NetBIOS computer name: 
|   Workgroup: WORKGROUP
|_  System time: 2015-12-22T17:01:33-08:00
```

I was able to get the values into a better format using `grep "for\|Windows"`

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.xx.xx1
|   OS: Windows XP (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.xx.xx5
|   OS: Windows 2000 (Windows 2000 LAN Manager)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.xx.xx8
Nmap scan report for 192.168.xx.x15
```

I am now trying to get the value (grep) of the previous line, if the next line contains a "|" character, but I have no idea how. I have tried using `tr "|" "\b"` but that did not work

**Input (stored in a text file)**

```
Line 1
|   Line2
Line 3
|   Line 4
Line 5
|   Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
|   Line 10
Line 11
```

**Desired Output**

```
Line 1
Line 3
Line 5
Line 9
```

Comment: Given your example input as the file `input`: `grep -B1 '|' input | grep -v '|'`

Comment: `nmap` also has an XML output mode (`-oX file.xml`) on which you could then use XPath or CSS selectors to pull out what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could do without `grep` e.g with `sed` you could save the line with the IP to hold buffer and copy it over the pattern space only when OS is Windows (deleting all other lines):

```
... | sed '/^Nmap scan report for/h;/^|[[:blank:]]*OS: Windows/!d;g'
```

or, in a similar manner, with `awk`, this time printing only the IP instead of the whole line:

```
... | awk '/^Nmap scan report for/{t=$5};/^\|[[:blank:]]*OS: Windows/{print t}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e'$!N;/\n|/P;D' \
<<""
Line 1
|   Line2
Line 3
|   Line 4
Line 5
|   Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
|   Line 10
Line 11
```

---

```
Line 1
Line 3
Line 5
Line 9
```

---

If it gets deeper...

```
sed -e'/^ *|/!{$!N;/\n|/P;}' -eD \
<<""
Line 1
|   Line2
|   Line 3
|___|   Line 4
    |   Line 5
    |___Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
|   Line 10
Line 11
```

---

```
Line 1
Line 9
```

You can drop `grep` w/ ...

```
sed -ne'/^Nmap.* /!{/^|.*: Win.*(W/!d;}' \
    -e's///;/)/H;x;s/\n/: (W/p' \
<<""
Nmap scan report for 192.168.xx.xxx
Host is ...
bla... and more ...
and bla and so on...
#
Host script results:
| smb-os-discovery:
|   OS: not windows Server (R) ... !(Windows Server (R) 2008 Standard 6.0)
|   OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2008::sp1
|   Comp ... some words ...
|   Net... more words ...
|   Work... words again ...
|_  Sys...
#
Nmap scan report for 192.168.xx.xxx
Host is ...
MAC Address:
#
Host script results:
| smb-os-discovery:
|   OS: Windows Server (R) 2008 Standard 6001 Service Pack 1 (Windows Server (R) 2008 Standard 6.0)
|_  System time: 2015-12-22T17:01:33-08:00
```

---

```
192.168.xx.xxx: (Windows Server (R) 2008 Standard 6.0)
```